# scrollTo() after orientationchange in Safari / iOS not working

Tags: jquery, scroll, safari, orientation-changes

here's my code:

```
function handleOrientationChange() {
    //$body.animate({scrollTop: 0});
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
$window.on('orientationchange', handleOrientationChange);
```

on Android devices it works fine, however when used on iOS Safari the window.scrollTo(0,0) is not working. Hitting window.scrollTo(0,0) in console works as expected. Using $body.animate({scrollTop:0}) instead of native scrollTo works. I tried also moving native code to next tick:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
}, 0);
```

Not working either.

**What's inside jQuery's animate() which makes it work?** I though it may be related t animation queueing, but passing {queue: false} in .animation as opt object doesn't stop it working so it's not queue related.
**Why native code is not working on mobile Safari?**